# How can we automatically translate SharePoint sites into multiple languages using SharePoint Online? E.g. English to French?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am using SharePoint Online and want to create my company's intranet site bilingual. I learned that it can only be done manually now using SharePoint. Is there any way to make this task automatic, so that anytime a page is created an equivalent page will be created in some other language?

Comment: Automatic language translation has gone by the way-side due to inaccuracies. While there may be 3rd parties that offer this support with SPO, Microsoft no longer does having dropped the Machine Translation Service some time ago. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-multilingual-communication-sites-pages-and-news-2bb7d610-5453-41c6-a0e8-6f40b3ed750c.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it with SharePoint out-of-the-box, although it can be done with a third party product.  The Machine Translation Service still exists, but has no UI, it can't translate modern pages, and it is old inaccurate translation technology, very slow, and error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other replies, you can check out this document to see what is currently offered by Microsoft for multiple languages in SharePoint Online: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/business/sharepoint/

One thing for sure, auto-translation for SharePoint pages is not included.